# Javascript function to manage (disable and check) some checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a problem with this simple Javascript code:

```
function select_checkbox(i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case 3: 
        if (document.upload_form.3.checked=true)
        {   
            document.upload_form.4.checked=true; 
            document.upload_form.4.disabled=true; 
            document.upload_form.5.checked=true; 
            document.upload_form.5.disabled=true;
        }

        if (document.upload_form.3.checked=false)
        {   
            document.upload_form.4.checked=false; 
            document.upload_form.4.disabled=false; 
            document.upload_form.5.checked=false; 
            document.upload_form.5.disabled=false;
        }  

        break;

        [other code]
```

associated with this HTML code:

```
     <input type="checkbox" name="3" onclick="select_checkbox(3)" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="4" onclick="select_checkbox(4)" /> 
     <input type="checkbox" name="5" onclick="select_checkbox(5)" />
```

I would like to do this:

- if I select the checkbox "3", check and disable 4 and 5
- if I select the checkbox "4", check and disable 3 + uncheck and disable 5
- if I select the checkbox "5", uncheck and disable 3 and 4
- when unselected re-enable and uncheck all

The first part of the code (I report only the part of the checkbox "3") works good but I have a problem with restore the configuration by un-check the checkbox.

Comment: You're setting, not checking, variables. `=` instead of `==` (or `===`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (document.upload_form.3.checked=true)
{ 
}

should be replaced by

if (document.upload_form.3.checked==true)
{
}
```

that should be ==

Answer (score 1):

You cant access property starting with a digit through dot syntax, use `[]` syntax. Also you are doing assignment instead of comparison in your if statement.

```
    function select_checkbox(i)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 3: 
            if (document.upload_form['3'].checked)
            {   
                document.upload_form['4'].checked=true; 
                document.upload_form['4'].disabled=true; 
                document.upload_form['5'].checked=true; 
                document.upload_form['5'].disabled=true;
            }

            if (!document.upload_form['3'].checked)
            {   
                document.upload_form['4'].checked=false; 
                document.upload_form['4'].disabled=false; 
                document.upload_form['5'].checked=false; 
                document.upload_form['5'].disabled=false;
            }  

            break;

                            [other code]
```